# Best practice conditional variable assignment in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, conditional-statements

A very easy typescript question, which I need assistance with

Without using if statements, how would I conditional assign something to a constant variable

```
const myConstant = myProduct.productId;
```

I want it so that if the productId in myProduct is empty (""), it will assign the variable of myConstant to "No Product", I wish to do this without utilizing if statements.

Thanks

How would I go about doing this.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you could do it...

```
const myConstant = myProduct.productId || 'No Product';
```

Also, if you'd like to do `null` check for `myProduct` as well, you could put `?` for it, like below

```
const myConstant = myProduct?.productId || 'No Product';
```

PS: this would work with empty strings, `null`, `undefined` and with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
const myConstant = myProduct.productId || 'No Product';
```

This is called Short Circuit Evalution in JavaScript

Read more here : https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-is-short-circuit-evaluation-ff22b2f5608c

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like :

`const myConstant = myProduct?.productId || 'No Product';`